# 'Registration' object has no attribute 'geometry'

Tags: python, tkinter

i am working with tkinter python.
now creating a simple registration page. so i made a class.
then initiate with the parameter and parent.

from main, i pass a TK(). so i can expect, it can initiate with a geometry.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


def pass_show():
    p = password.get()
    print(p)


class Registration(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        self.geometry("600x600")
        self.title("Registration")
        reg = Label(self, text="Registration").place(x=210, y=40)
        name = Label(self, text="Name").place(x=130, y=150)
        username = Label(self, text="Username").place(x=130, y=190)
        admin_id = Label(self, text="Admin ID").place(x=130, y=230)
        email = Label(self, text="Email").place(x=130, y=270)
        passLabel = Label(self, text="Password").place(x=130, y=310)
        password = StringVar()
        e1 = Entry(self).place(x=210, y=150)
        e2 = Entry(self).place(x=210, y=190)
        e3 = Entry(self).place(x=210, y=230)
        e4 = Entry(self).place(x=210, y=270)
        e5 = Entry(self, textvariable=password, show='*').place(x=210, y=310)
        submit = Button(self, text="Submit", command=pass_show).place(x=130, y=350)

    def close_window(self):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    print(root)
    run = Registration(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

the error from terminal ->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    run = Registration(root)
  File "main.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.initialize_user_interface()
  File "main.py", line 17, in initialize_user_interface
    self.geometry("600x600")
AttributeError: 'Registration' object has no attribute 'geometry'
```

where is the problem?

Comment: A frame doesn't have a geometry attribute. You can set that only for the window, e.g. `root.geometry("600x600")`

Comment: Furthering what @Wups said, all you need to do is replace `self.geometry` with `root.geometry` and it should work fine.

Comment: or `self.parent.geometry(..)` is what your looking for? and you will have the error in the next line, so change that to, `self.parent.title(..)`

Comment: thanks i changed the code. finally a box appeared. but none of those widget works.

Comment: @Dip you need to `pack()`, `grid`or `place` your frame on your root window otherwise it will be there but non-visible. so `run.pack()` is missing here

Comment: For normal practice, it is not recommended to call `.geometry()` and `.title()` inside an instance of widget other than `Tk()` or `Toplevel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead
self.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 250)

happy coding :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).